# Leaving @typescript-eslint/require-await on, but exempting individual instances?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have a project where there have recently been a slew of recent bugs where async functions are not being awaited, resulting in some test infrastructure timeouts.  We use typescript-esling, and I'd love to be able to enable the flag `@typescript-eslint/require-await` as an error, but there are times that I want exceptions: intentionally unawaited async calls.

Is there JS/TS syntax I can use to indicate to the linter that a given line has been intentionally not awaited?  I'm hoping there's something similar to how discards will avoid the "variable not used" rule.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put a `void` in front of the unawaited promise. (potentially needs another rule to allow this, depending on your presets)